# Three.js Mesh at Clipping Plane Distorted

Tags: three.js, webgl

I have a scene with a globally applied clipping plane and I want to be able to visualise this plane by adding a mesh made from it, which I've then added an alpha to. This mesh is made from PlaneBufferGeometry.

The problem is when the scene renders, the plane mesh used to show the clipping plane, appears all fuzzy. [fuzzy mesh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6c9oM.png)
Presumably this is because the renderer is trying to clip at this thin geometry? Is there any settings I can enable to stop this? I think I could maybe get around this by only applying the clipping locally to all other meshes or using a thin box geometry instead of a Plane one but I'd rather avoid either of these two if there's something simpler.

Comment: A picture here could really be worth a thousand words.

Comment: Added a link to the fuzzy mesh

Comment: Use local clipping. https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_clipping_intersection.html